# Why does the Javascript object show so many levels of hierarchy ? How to declare and access it correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

```
export interface NowChannelInterface {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  isSelected: Boolean;
}

export interface NowChannellistInterface {
  nowChannelList: NowChannelInterface[];
}

const initialState: NowChannellistInterface = {
  nowChannelList: [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'CNN',
      isSelected: true
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'BBC',
      isSelected: true
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'NDTV',
      isSelected: true
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'QTV',
      isSelected: true
    }
  ]
};

state: NowChannellistInterface = initialState;
const chx: any = { id: 1, name: 'BBC', isSelected: true};
cur_channel: NowChannelInterface = chx;
channels: any = state
console.log(channels);
```

Then initialState is copied to channels,
Any suggestion around alternate way of declaring is also welcome but note I have to keep the above two as interface than class to be able to use it with observables.

Then in console when I try to use:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are a compile time feature of typescript that enable powerful tooling, static type checking, and the ability to express APIs in a clean declarative fashion. Like all aspects of TypeScript, they are not manifest in the compiled output. The output is just JavaScript.

Also, what you have is a hierarchical data structure. It is an `Array` of `Object`s. The debugger allows expanding the contents of the array, and in turn expanding the contents of each object using a convenient, tree based visualization approach. The same information is available without the debugger simply by using member access notation - `.property` or `['property']`.

The only way to reduce such nesting is to nest to a lesser degree.

However, I am not sure why you would want to do that.

The code you have looks perfectly reasonable. Your interface names exhibit poor style, the `Interface` suffix should be dropped as it is very unidiomatic, but other than that I do not see a specific reason for concern.

One thing worth noting is that it appears you have an extra level of property nesting. This makes the API a bit awkward to use. Without seeing more code it is difficult to say but you likely have something like

```
const channels = { nowChannelList: initialState };
```

somewhere.

This could be rewritten as

```
const channels = { nowChannelList: initialState.nowChannelList };
```

channels itself could be simplified to

```
const channels = initialState.nowChannelList;
```

but I assume you wrote it this way for a reason.

The following is an example of less nested code, just to clarify

```js
const initialState = {
  nowChannelList: [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: 'CNN',
      isSelected: true
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'BBC',
      isSelected: true
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'NDTV',
      isSelected: true
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'QTV',
      isSelected: true
    }
  ]
};

const channels = initialState.nowChannelList;

console.log(channels);
```

Comment: I don't understand in first place how this hierarchy is being generated, `nowChannelList> nowChannelList> nowChannelList> nowChannelList`. I just did `channels=initialState`

Comment: What do you want `channels` to contain? If you don't want nesting don't nest. I.e. write `channels = initialState.nowChanelList;`.

Comment: It sounds like you have a bug and are writing `channels = { nowChannelList: initialState };` that is the only way to get that output.

Comment: I added more code, simplified untyped js works fine as you are showed but with type assignment and typecasting in typescript is screwing up things.

Comment: There is no typecasting. TypeScript does not have any runtime behavior.

Comment: I remove `: NowChannellistInterface` and `: any` types from the code, it works as you mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141312/discussion-between-aluan-haddad-and-ishandutta2007).

Comment: found the issue. chrome is caching past states. even hard reload is not working. opening server in incognito mode solved it. there is no hierarchy now for objects either. it was introduced by some intial code which the browser was caching.